# Better memory viewer add-in for Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio

The memory viewer in Visual Studio is extremely basic, and I am wondering if there are any add-ins for VS that replace or augment it, that I can't find by searching.

Stuff I'm missing (all of them optional but would be great):

- The ability to view data on the right hand side as different data types (floats, int32s, etc - not just chars)
- Track location in the left hand side, when I place cursor in the right hand side
- Easily view the address of the current cursor placement without the need for mental hex arithmetic
- Searching memory areas for strings or values in different data types

I'd be happy to find ANYTHING that's better than the built in barebones one.

I'm using VS2008, but would happily switch to VS2010 if it makes a difference.